# spyder IDE sidebar, rename, find all occurances?

Tags: python, ide, spyder

I have some questions about spyder 3.2.4 ide for python:

1. The "sidebar" (to the right of the main code-window) which marks all lines with warnings, all lines with todo etc with a small colored marker. Can I set these colors? Can I disable which ones to show?
2. Can I "smart rename" a variable like in other IDEs? I mean not just text replace, but actually make sure i just rename the selected variable (all occurances and nothing but it) and not just text matching a string i type in like i would in "word".
3. Can I list all occurances of a variable like in other IDEs? Lets say I have a list called "combinedAreas" and want to list all the uses of that variable, preferably also being ablo to click a line and jump to that line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) About your questions:

> Can I set these colors?

No

> Can I disable which ones to show?

Yes, you can do that by going to

`Preferences > Editor > Code Introspection/Analysis > Analysis`

> Can I "smart rename" a variable like in other IDEs?

Not right now, but we're trying to implement this feature for Spyder 4 (our next major release).

> Can I list all occurances of a variable like in other IDEs?

No, but it's also planned for Spyder 4.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However can i really choose which ones to show? I find only a few checkboxes. The one called "real-tile analysis" disables some of the right-side bar but i cannot choose anything.

For example "todo" seems to show up on the right-side, I dont want this. I would like to tick "show all occurances" for example. Many IDE:s have these "right-side marks" (i dont know what they are called) rather customizable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Please open an issue in our [issues tracker](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues) with a screenshot of how that's handled by other IDEs.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Hi this is Felix from the future, the year 2020. Now I am using Spyder 4.1.3 (pi backwards!). Is a rename or list occurrences feature available?